# Alternative command (ActiveSheet)

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions, worksheet

There is user-defined function (UDF), which is located on all worksheets of the workbook.

How can I refer to the worksheet in which the function is located?

I am using `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet`, but the results are constantly changing.

```
Function äëÿñèò(Diapozon As Range) As Long
      'äëÿ ñèòóàöèè
    Application.Volatile
    Dim n As Long
    Dim C As Range
    Dim m As Long

    m = -1
    n = 0
    For Each C In Diapozon.Rows

    If C.Value = 1 Then
     m = m + 1
    If ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(101, 42 + (m * 21)).Value = 1 Then
    n = n + 1
    End If
    End If
    Next C

    äëÿñèò = n
End Function
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Application.Caller` to refer to the cell which is calling the function, therefore you can use `Application.Caller.Worksheet` to refer to that cell's worksheet.